# Script to send email alert only when process change state

Tags: shell-script, process, aix

Below script checks  whether MStrsvr process is running or not . The issue I'm facing is if i schedule a cron tab to run this script for every 1 hour it will throw email alert every 1hr that "MSTRSvr is running"  which i don't want . I want the script to throw alert only when server is stopped/started.

```
#!/bin/ksh
hos=$(hostname)

curr_Dt=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

var=$(ps -ef | grep -i '[/]MSTRSvr')

if [ -z "$var" ]
then

    echo "ALERT TIME : $curr_Dt" >>wa.txt
    echo "SERVER NAME : $hos" >>wa.txt
    echo "\n \n" >>wa.txt
    echo " MSTRSvr is not running on $hos Please check for possible impact " >>wa.txt
    echo "\n \n" >>wa.txt

    mail -s "MSTRSvr process ALERT" abc@aaa.com <wa.txt

else

    echo "MSTRSvr is running" >>mi.txt

    mail -s "MSTRSvr process ALERT" abc@aaa.com <mi.txt

fi

rm wa.txt 2>ni.txt
rm mi.txt 2>ni.txt
```

Comment: Remove the code in the `else` part?

Comment: if i remove the code in else path when the  process is restarted it wont throw alert that "the process is running " ..! thats the challenge im facing here . 
1.process stop --> email alert should be triggered 
2.when process is started  again--> email alert should be triggered only once .rest of the time when process is running it should not throw email alert .

Comment: Then store last state in a file inside `/tmp/` and add a check for the content of that file.

Comment: i have never tried it before ..can post a sample syntax to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#!/bin/ksh

hos=$(hostname)
curr_Dt=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# I am going to get the process ID for the MSTRSvr.
ProcessPID=$(ps -ef | grep -i '[/]MSTRSvr' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}') 

if [[ -z ${ProcessPID} ]]; then
    # There is no PID, Not running!
    echo "ALERT TIME : $curr_Dt" >>wa.txt
    echo "SERVER NAME : $hos" >>wa.txt
    echo "\n \n" >>wa.txt
    echo " MSTRSvr is not running on $hos Please check for possible impact " >>wa.txt
    echo "\n \n" >>wa.txt
    mail -s "MSTRSvr process ALERT" abc@aaa.com <wa.txt
else
    # The process is running check it against the last recorded PID.
    # You can also compare /tmp/MSTRSvr.pid with ${ProcessPID}.
    kill -0 `cat /tmp/MSTRSvr.pid` > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
       # The current PID does not match.
       echo "MSTRSvr was restarted." >>mi.txt
       # Update the tempfile with current running PID.
       echo ${ProcessPID}>/tmp/MSTRSvr.pid
       mail -s "MSTRSvr process ALERT" abc@aaa.com <mi.txt
    fi
fi

rm wa.txt 2>ni.txt
rm mi.txt 2>ni.txt
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Before running this script for the first time, create the /tmp/MSTRSvr.pid file and add '999999999'(random number) to the file, The check under 'else' command will fail and you will receive email saying 'MSTRSvr was restarted' ignore that and continue...

So every interval script will check for the PID and then checks it against the last known PID.

Comment: thanks you so much . could you please explain what this line does ?
kill -0 `cat /tmp/MSTRSvr.pid` > /dev/null 2>&1 
will it kill the original MSTRSvr process ?

Comment: No, signal number 0 will not kill the process, it will return 0 if the process is active and non-zero if it is not.

Comment: thank you for sharing these many information's.last help is it a good practice to use  temporary .txt files and then remove it using rm command ? is there any other good practice to store temporary information in a file  and remove it . (like how i stored all information in wa.txt and mi.txt  and sent it as a mail )

Comment: It depends on situation, If this is a critical operation I would write tmp file in to a folder where only you have access to as /tmp is accessible by all the users and there is good chance file getting deleted or modified.

Answer (score 0):

Add a test for the last state of the server:

```
#!/bin/ksh
hos=$(hostname)

curr_Dt=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

var=$(ps -ef | grep -i '[/]MSTRSvr')

if [ -z "$var" ]
then
    echo "ALERT TIME : $curr_Dt" >>wa.txt
    echo "SERVER NAME : $hos" >>wa.txt
    echo "\n \n" >>wa.txt
    echo " MSTRSvr is not running on $hos Please check for possible impact " >>wa.txt
    echo "\n \n" >>wa.txt

    echo "stopped" > "filewithlaststate.txt"

    mail -s "MSTRSvr process ALERT" abc@aaa.com <wa.txt

else

    if [ "$(cat "filewithlaststate.txt")" != "running" ]
    then 
         echo "MSTRSvr is running" >>mi.txt

         echo "running" > "filewithlaststate.txt"

         mail -s "MSTRSvr process ALERT" abc@aaa.com <mi.txt
    fi

fi

rm wa.txt 2>ni.txt
rm mi.txt 2>ni.txt
```

Comment: thank you for sharing  me another way of approaching this issue .